# RestFB - I publish a photo album on my facebook but my friends doesn´t see it

Tags: facebook, photo, restfb

I made an application that publishes photo albums on my facebook account.
It used to work months ago, but now the albums that the app publishes are not public.
Looking my facebook, the albums have public permissions, but my friends can´t see them. Only the ones that I uploaded manually through Facebook.

```
FacebookType  publishPhotoResponse = (FacebookType) facebookClient.publish("me/albums", FacebookType.class,Parameter.with("name", album));
String idAlbum=publishPhotoResponse.getId();
publishPhotoResponse = (FacebookType) facebookClient.publish(idAlbum+"/photos", FacebookType.class, BinaryAttachment.with(file.getName(), is), Parameter.with("message", texto));
```

I appreciate your help, I don´t know what else to do.
Andrea